# How to make a docker container communicate with the localstack docker container with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am setting up an application inside a docker container. I want this application to be able to connect with the localstack stack container [localstack docs](https://localstack.cloud/). When i run `docker-compose up` the containers start up successfully. I can run a seperate java application not included with in docker-compose file that will connect successfully to the localstack container. But the application that starts up along with the localstack cannot connect. Ive looked at the docker docs and localstack docs and I cant figure out how to get these things to communicate with one another. Any help would be greatly apprecaited. Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

services:
  jc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
      - PORT=5001
      network: host
    image: jc
    depends_on:
    - localstack
    container_name: jc
    ports:
    - 5001:5001
    links:
    - localstack
    environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
    - "4567-4584:4567-4584"
```

The error message that I get is:

> sqs.SqsPoller app=jc version=2.0.1.0 : An exception occurred while polling for messages: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:4576 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this error

> Connect to localhost:4576 [**localhost/127.0.0.1**] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Seems you have the setting ready in service `jc`, you need the same for your problem application.

```
links:
- localstack
```

I guess your application is running in another docker as well, not on host directly. So  you can't access `localhost:4567` from application container, because these aws emulated services are not reachable in container itself. Two solutions:

1. link the localstack container to your application. for example if the link name is `localstack`, then you can access service with `localstack:4567`
2. get the real IP address of host, access with `IP:4567`

Comment: I dont understand. Links: -localstack is already in the jc service. If i try to add Links to localstack i get an error when running docker-compose. Are you saying that the aws services should be available on host localstack? Not localhost?

Comment: I have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStack gave us initial struggle to configure. We run it locally using docker-compose and on GitLab using services. We were using it for S3 services

```
 localstack:
    container_name: "localstack"
    image: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Now this gets read in the Spring Bean and for connection we use **http://localstack:4566** in the url. http://localhost:4566 works on within the container, outside the container it has to be http://localstack:4566

```
 @Bean
  AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {
    var endpoint = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localstack:4566", s3ConfigProperties.getRegion());
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint).enablePathStyleAccess().build();
  }
```

For the GitLab deployment, we use below config in **services**

```
services:
- name: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
      alias: localstack
      command: [ "--port","4566","--expose", "4566" ]
```

And as the functional tests running inside the docker container, S3 config url would need to be **http://localhost:4566**

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Put `http://localstack` as  `custom.localstack.host` in the `serverless.yml` configuration.

### More info:

While not officially deprecated, the "links" functionality in Docker Compose is considered outdated and not recommended for modern Docker environment setups anymore. Therefore, I had to find an alternative solution to enable communication between the containers. I'm using a similar structure which includes:

- a Docker container that stores the main application and development configurations with project-specific versions for dependencies to avoid host environment pollution
- a LocalStack Docker container that mocks AWS services in my local environment
- and a Docker Compose file that connects all of these containers

#### Solution

The key in my case was to provide properly the LocalStack `host` so it won't try to connect to the default `localhost`, but instead it will target the LocalStack instance served by the Docker container.

#### Example

- `serverless.yml`

In the `custom.localstack.host` section, you can specify the name of the service as it appears in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I prefer to prefix my Docker containers and group them by project, so I use `example-localstack`, but you can choose any name you like (or keep it simple with `localstack`).

*Note: It's worth mentioning to remember to prefix the name with `http://` so it's recognized as a valid host. For example, this step is not necessary if you're setting up a MongoDB container and establishing connections from another Docker container but it was not the case with LocalStack, it's required to do so.*

```
service: example

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-deployment-bucket
  - serverless-localstack

functions: ${file(./functions.yaml)}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-central-1
  deploymentBucket:
    name: example-deployments
    serverSideEncryption: AES256

package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - dist/**
    - node_modules/**

custom:
  localstack:
    stages:
      - local
    host: http://example-localstack
    debug: true
```

- `docker-compose.yml` for reference

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  example-app:
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME?}-APP
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  example-localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # External services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```