# Testing with LocalStack in a dockerized python environment

Tags: python, docker-compose, pytest, localstack

When developing a dockerized AWS application locally, it's a common practice to simulate Amazon's services using LocalStack. One way to get the Python application talking to LocalStack at test-time is to [monkeypatch the Boto Client and ServiceResource](https://github.com/localstack/localstack-python-client/blob/master/README.md), and [use the "link" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295524/how-to-make-a-docker-container-communicate-with-the-localstack-docker-container) in the docker-compose file.

Unfortunately the Docker-Compose reference manual advises against this. It seems that Docker might remove the link feature. Instead they recommend that we should use the internal networks feature of a docker-compose file. This mean that instead of accessing the LocalStack services via localhost (e.g. http://localhost:4566) it will be via something like http://localstack:4566, provided the service-name was "localstack".

Is there a way to change the monkey-patch configuration so that this works? This is the standard monkey-patch code:

```py
import localstack_client.session
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def boto3_localstack_patch(monkeypatch):
    session_ls = localstack_client.session.Session()
    monkeypatch.setattr(boto3, "client", session_ls.client)
    monkeypatch.setattr(boto3, "resource", session_ls.resource)
```

There's no obvious way to indicate that the tests ought to use a different hostname, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def boto3_localstack_patch(monkeypatch):
    session_ls = localstack_client.session.Session(localstack_host="localstack")
    monkeypatch.setattr(boto3, "client", session_ls.client)
    monkeypatch.setattr(boto3, "resource", session_ls.resource)
```

The `localstack_client.session.Session()` object takes an argument `localstack_host` which can be used to specify how to connect to LocalStack if not on localhost.